# nodejs & express https server with NGINX

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, https

I'm trying to setup a nodejs server with https to make REST calls to. 
Connecting directly to ip + port through http works fine. When using https with ip and port my android app complains that "the Hostname xx.xx.xx.xx not verified". So I figured I should setup a domain for it to make my certificate match.

With NGINX I made the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name rest-ssl.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         https://xx.xx.xx.xx:4443;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name rest-normal.mydomain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4080;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

And restarted my nginx service. In this config file I have two other server configs listening on port 80 that works fine.

My nodejs app looks like the following:

```
var express =          require('express'),
    http =             require('http'),
    https =            require('https'),
    fs =               require('fs'),
    Security =         require('./security.js'),
    json =             require('express-json'),
    stylus =           require('stylus'),
    nib =              require('nib'),
    path =             require('path'),
    bodyParser =       require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(json());
app.use(authChecker);
app.use(stylus.middleware({
        src: __dirname + '/public',
        compile: compile,
        keepExtensions: true,
        uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/images'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('./routes-v1.js')(app);
require('./routes-v2.js')(app);

var hskey = fs.readFileSync('certificates/key.pem');
var hscert = fs.readFileSync('certificates/key-cert.pem');

var options = {
    key: hskey,
    cert: hscert
};

http.createServer(app).listen(4080);
console.log('Listening on port 4080...');

https.createServer(options, app).listen(4443);
console.log('Listening on port 4443...');

function authChecker(req, res, next) {
    console.log("authChecker");
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if (!Security.checkHMAC(req)) {
        res.json({unauthorized:true});
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

function compile(str, path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path).use(nib());
}
```

My problem is that the newly defined urls in NGINX doesn't work. The IP's work fine. What am I missing here? Is it something in NGINX or in node? My other subdomains through NGINX works flawlessly.

Comment: Enable logging and check logs fro errors.

Comment: logging of node or is there a way to log nginx? Because I've tried in node and don't get anything when going through the url. Node doesn't even get the call.

Comment: Configure nginx to write logs first. Then try to see if there is any error when you run nginx and try enter https url. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps